# Why did Jesus tell Satan to do it quickly?

Tags: jesus, satan

> And after the sop Satan entered into him. Then said Jesus unto him, That thou doest, do **quickly**. John 13:27 KJV

Why couldn't it be slow?

Comment: Jesus was talking to Judas, which is why Judas was the one who went out. Read the next three verses,

Comment: His thesis is weakened by the argument that both the pronouns Εκεινον and αυτω are in the dative case, referring to the same person, moreover, σατανας (Satan) and Jesus are in the nominative case, being the main objects of the verse and this whole argument. it is still supported by the preposition εις, which internalizes the entire dialogue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In John 13:27, the adjective τάχιον = "more quickly", ie, the comparative adjective.  Thus, the verse should strictly be translated,

> And after the morsel, then Satan entered into him. Therefore Jesus
> says to him, "What you do, do more quickly."

Thus, Jesus is telling Judas/Satan to do things even more quickly than he had planned!  This is confirmed by the form of the verb "do" ποίησον = imperative - a command of Jesus.

Note these insightful comments from Cambridge:

> **do quickly** Literally, **do more quickly**; carry it out at once, even sooner than has been planned. Now that the winning back of Judas
> has become hopeless, delay was worse than useless: it merely kept Him
> from His hour of victory. Comp. Matthew 23:32.

Ellicott is similar:

> **That thou doest, do quickly**.—The Greek is exactly, more quickly.
> “Carry out your plans even more quickly than you have proposed. Do the
> fatal deed at once. It is resolved, and every effort to win thee has
> failed. A fixed resolve is nothing less than the deed itself.”

Benson offers a further insight:

> **Then said Jesus, That thou doest, do quickly** — This is not a permission, much less a command. It is only as if he had said, If thou
> art determined to do it, why dost thou delay? Hereby showing Judas
> that he could not be hid, and expressing his own readiness to suffer.

Barnes is also helpful:

> ... He calls upon them to act decisively, firmly, immediately. He does
> not allow them the privilege to deliberate about wicked deeds, but
> calls on them to act at once, and to show whether they will obey or
> disobey him; whether they will serve him, or whether they will betray
> fits cause. He knows all their plans, as Jesus did that of Judas, and
> he calls on men to act under the full conviction that he knows all
> their soul. Sin thus is a vast evil. When men can sin knowing that God
> sees it all, it shows that the heart is fully set in them to do evil,
> and that there is nothing that will restrain them.